# Countdown Time in Android

Tags: java, android, countdowntimer

I am developing an Android app and I have a requirement to:

1) Countdown time from `'x' minutes` to `'1' minute` and then once it is at `1 minute`, count in terms of `60 sec, 30 sec` and then `0`.

I am counting down in terms of 1 min(60000).

My code is:

```
public void countdowntimer(long timeinmillis, long countdowninterval){
        Log.d("hi","Iamhere 0" + timeinmillis/60000);
        new CountDownTimer(timeinmillis, countdowninterval) {

            public void onTick(long timeinmillis) {


                //Countdown the time in terms of minutes

                Log.d("hi","Iamhere 2" + timeinmillis);
                tv.setText(String.valueOf((timeinmillis)/60000) + "min");
                rootView.invalidate();
                if(timeinmillis <= 60000 && timeinmillis > 30000){
                   tv.setText(String.valueOf(60) + "sec");
                    rootView.invalidate();
                }else if(timeinmillis < 30000){
                    tv.setText(String.valueOf(30) + "sec");
                    rootView.invalidate();
                }
            }

            public void onFinish() {

            }
        }.start();
    }
```

The logs are:

```
Iamhere0 4

Iamhere1 3
```

Why is my second log showing 1 minute lesser than first log and how do I implement 60sec, 30sec countdown once it is at 1 minute?

The expected output is:

```
4 min

3 min

2 min

1 min -> 60sec

30sec

0
```

Comment: If you include a expected output you should receive higher quality answers

Comment: Simply because the onTick already substract the first interval value... For the format, just use check if the time remaining is lower than ...

Comment: Still not working..please see the edited code

Comment: If you can wait 8hours, I can post my timer using system time instead of an int value. This is more precise and update easily a Textview or anything else. But it is on my home laptop...
The printed value is calculated an in you case, just need a little update to show only minutes if needed.

Comment: Yeah sure that would be helpful thank you :)

Comment: @Mark023, a bit late I guess but I finally find some time to post my version. This is a simplify version but this is really easy to use and reusable.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use `AtomicInteger` to **maintain the threads condition**.

In First Condition its display **time in minute**

```
 if (min.get() > 1) {
                        mCount.setText(Integer.toString(min.get())+" min");
                        handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
                        min.getAndDecrement();
                    }
```

**AND**

In Last one minute its goes to second condition which display **time in seconds**

```
else {

                    if(min.get()== 1) {
                        mCount.setText("60 Sec");
                        handler.postDelayed(this, 500);
                    }
                    else if(min.get() == 0){
                        mCount.setText("30 Sec");
                        handler.postDelayed(this, 500);
                    }
                    else
                        mCount.setText("0 Sec");
                        min.getAndDecrement();
                }
```

Use this ...........

```
final TextView mCount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.count);
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        final AtomicInteger min = new AtomicInteger(4);
        final Runnable counter = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                if (min.get() > 1) {
                    mCount.setText(Integer.toString(min.get())+" min");
                    handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
                    min.getAndDecrement();
                } else {

                    if(min.get()== 1) {
                        mCount.setText("60 Sec");
                        handler.postDelayed(this, 500);
                    }
                    else if(min.get() == 0){
                        mCount.setText("30 Sec");
                        handler.postDelayed(this, 500);
                    }
                    else
                        mCount.setText("0 Sec");
                        min.getAndDecrement();
                }

            }
        };
        handler.postDelayed(counter, 0);
```

enjoy coding.....

Comment: Thank you for the code... So my countdown interval is 60000ms . So where do i use this

Comment: Ok but in this code i dont understand where you specify the starting time of minutes. Suppose I need to count back from 4 minutes, these 4 minutes where do you specify

Comment: And you are using to different value to calculate the minutes and the seconds, since both a related you should try to work with only one.

Comment: @sushildlh, didn't receive a notification from your comment (not sur why) but I just remembered this question so, I did post my answer You can look at my way, I am open to critics.

Answer (score 1):

It took me some time to answer it, this was my holydays ... but here is one other solution if this is still interresting for anyone.

I prefer to use System.currentTimeInMilli to manage the timer. When I start it, I calculate the time to end then on each tick, I calculate the remaining time to show.

This design prevent the delay you will find with any incremental/decremental variable timer. To keep this class reusable, I used the Observer pattern, on each tick (100ms on this example), the Observable instance will be send to each observer.

```
public class RunnableTimer extends Observable implements Runnable {

    private final Handler handler;
    // Number of milliseconds to run before the end
    private Long delay;
    // Date in millis until the end of the timer
    private Long countDownEnd = null;
    //The calculate remaining time
    private long time;

    public RunnableTimer(Observer o){
        this.handler = new Handler();
        addObserver(o);
    }

    /**
     * Start the timer
     * @param delay : the number of milliseconds to run
     */
    public void start(Long delay){
        this.delay = delay;

        countDownEnd = System.currentTimeMillis() + delay;
        handler.postDelayed(this, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        time = countDownEnd - System.currentTimeMillis();

        if (time > 0)
            handler.postDelayed(this, 100); //Recalculate every 100ms, to keep some precision... can be more or less.
        else
            time = 0; //to prevent to show negative values

        sendUpdate();
    }


    public String toString(){
        long t = time / 1000;
        Log.d("time", "" + t);
        if(t >= 60){
            return String.format("%d min.", t/60);
        } if t <= 0){
            return "End";
        } else {
            return String.format("%d sec.", (t/30+1)*30);
        } 
    }

    /**
     * Send the instance to each observer.
     */
    private void sendUpdate(){
        setChanged();
        notifyObservers(toString());
    }
}
```

From this, you have a timer that use the system time to calculate the remaining time and the toString method that create the desire template.

To use it, simply create an instance with the Observer you want.

```
public class Test implements Observer {

    private RunnableTimer timer;

    public Test(){
        timer = new RunnableTimer(this);
        timer.start(65000) //65sec
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Observable observable, Object data) {
        if(data == timer){ //If the update comes from the timer
            Log.d("timer", timer.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

I had to clear a huge part of my class but this should works fine since this is simpler version.

EDIT : In your case, your activity / fragment should implements Observer and in the update, where I log the timer, you should put the toString result into you textfield.

Answer (score 0):

try like this ：

```
public class MyTimeCount extends CountDownTimer {
 private Button btn_code;

public MyTimeCount(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval,Button btn) {
    super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
    btn_code=btn;
}

@Override
public void onFinish() {
    btn_code.setText("Reacquire");
    btn_code.setEnabled(true);
}
@Override
public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished){
    btn_code.setEnabled(false);
    btn_code.setText(millisUntilFinished /1000+"s");

}

}
```